# $(\delta,\epsilon)$ Continuity Proof

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

$$
f(T) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2\\
f(T) = \begin{pmatrix}  \sin(x)\sin(y) \\y\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have to prove that f is a continuous function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$

My try ended up in a problem

for all $\epsilon>0$ Exist $\delta>0$ so that $\lVert T-a\rVert < \delta =\epsilon$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}^2$

to prove $\lVert f(T) -f(a)\rVert < \epsilon$

$$
\lVert f(T) -f(a)\rVert= \sqrt{\bigl[(\sin(x)\sin(y)-\sin(a_1)\sin(a_2)\bigr]^2+(y-a_2)^2}
$$

how can I prove  that  $\bigl[(\sin(x)\sin(y)-\sin(a_1)\sin(a_2)\bigr]^2 <(x-a_1)^2$ ? 
or  did i have a wrong  start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|\sin x\sin y-\sin a_1\sin a_2|\\
=|\sin x\sin y-\sin a_1\sin y+\sin a_1\sin y-\sin a_1\sin a_2|\\
\le |\sin x-\sin a_1|\cdot|\sin y|+|\sin a_1|\cdot|\sin y-\sin a_2|\\
\le |x-a_1|+|y-a_2|
$$

So:

$$(\sin x\sin y-\sin a_1\sin a_2)^2\le (|x-a_1|+|y-a_2|)^2\le 2(x-a_1)^2+2(y-a_2)^2$$

I used $|\sin\alpha-\sin\beta|\le|\alpha-\beta|$ (simple application of Mean Value Theorem), and $(\alpha+\beta)^2\le 2\alpha^2+2\beta^2$

Then you can say:

$\lVert f(T)-f(a)\rVert\le\sqrt{2(x-a_1)^2+3(y-a_2)^2}\le\sqrt{3(x-a_1)^2+3(y-a_2)^2}=\sqrt{3}\lVert T-a\rVert$

so you may take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 3}$

Comment: thanks  it was  tricky to multiply  with sin(a1)sin(y), but  i can not here  use Mean value theorem  coz  i don t  know  and i am not allowed to use  it in order to proof that |sin a   -sin b|  <= |a -b| , is an other  way to proof that ?

Comment: ah i found it thank you  :D

Comment: You may convert the difference to product: $|\sin x - \sin y|=2\big|\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\big|\cdot\big|\cos\frac{x+y}{2}\big|\le 2\big|\sin\frac{x-y}{2}\big|$ and use only $|\sin x|\le |x|$, if it looks easier to you.

Comment: nah i will use this  ,  let  be  $ c \in [a,b]$ ,$ and f(x) ⁼ sin(x) then
|f(a)-f(b)| \leq |f'(c)||b-a|$   $and |f'(x)| = |cos(c)| \leq 1 \Rightarrow     |f(a)-f(b)| \leq |b-a|$